# Launch youtube app from Android browser

Tags: android, browser, youtube

It used to be that if you clicked on an appropriate embed tag on a web page in the Android browser, it would launch the youtube app.  Now that the browser has its own youtube plugin, it seems to run that instead.

How can I get the old behavior?

Youtube's web pages still have the old behavior, but I can't understand their javascript.

Thanks,

Dawg

Answer (score 0):

A link like

YouTube Video

with video id does the trick.  See, for example,

http://it-ride.blogspot.com/2010/04/android-youtube-intent.html

Comment: That should be: &lt;a href="vnd.youtube:sdpw2Ow5f9M" &gt;YouTube Video&lt;/a&gt;